# flutter test command in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-test

if I click the 'RUN', then it will show that "Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';"

```
    /Users/mr8god/Softwares/flutter2/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --enable-asserts /Users/mr8god/OSPP/ProjectCode/ndef_integrate/finish/ndef/test/ndef_test.dart
../../../../../Softwares/flutter2/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/_goldens_io.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
../../../../../Softwares/flutter2/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/accessibility.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
../../../../../Softwares/flutter2/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/animation_sheet.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
```

Of course, I found a way to solve this. Just change the test directory and input the command "flutter test xxx.dart". It works.

So!!! I want to use the "RUN" button to achieve the same effect.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

How You install flutter plugin? Via Android Studio or manually? You do not have any informations form Android Studio (notifications, message or sth) that You do not have flutter (because A-S do not know about path to Your flutter installation)?

Try install Flutter from Android Studio, not manually, it looks like easiest way probably.

Comment: I have installed flutter. And the RUN command works. This problem is about "flutter test" in A-S.